# Weighting values using curves

Tags: special-functions, graphing-functions, curves

I am in the field of computer programming but I think my question is maths based. I have tried several google searches on this matter but nothing has come up with what I am looking for, probably because im not really sure what that is.

Take for example the following example. I charge my supplier for failing to provide orders on time say £100 each time. If I only have one order with a supplier though, and he fails it, I will only charge him 10% of that charge. If I have 100 orders with a supplier he will be charged 100% on every order he fails to provide on time.

I want to develop a function where I input the amount of orders with a supplier and this return a weight for this supplier, ie in the case above, a percentage. Within the function it would look up these values on a kind of curve which i could modify or calibrate to get the desired results.

Can someone point me in the right direction?